# Why wasn't Killer Bee recognized as the 5th Raikage?

Tags: naruto, boruto

After the Great Fourth Shinobi World War, all the Kages are heavily injured, especially the 4th Raikage who lost his hand (which was answered nicely by Ankit Sharma [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/40776/36522)).

Now, the 5th Raikage selected was Darui, a shinobi of Kumogakure and the right-hand-man of the 4th Raikage. He may be capable of this position & may have proved his worth in the War.

On the other hand, here is what I think of Killer Bee:

1. He is also a good & talented Shinobi.
2. He is the brother of the 4th Raikage.
3. He is a jinchuriki.
4. He has a well-controlled of his tailed beast. He even taught it to Naruto.
5. Even Minato, the 4th Hokage also praised Killer Bee on a fight with the 4th Raikage.
6. He's the master/sensei of Omoi, Samui, and Darui.
7. Having a good relationship with all other Kages.
8. Unique fight style which I absorbed.

Considering this, why wasn't Killer Bee recognized as the 5th Raikage?

Comment: why do you think Killer Bee would be better?

Comment: @Memor-X he is the brother of 4th raikage,master of  Omoi , Samui , and Darui too  as wells as he is good & talented shinobi who controls the tailed beast.When comes to age wise either talent wise he should be the 5th raikage. Having good relationship with all other kages & lands too especially with naruto. Is there any behind reason for unrecongnize him?

Comment: i didn't understand that second last sentence but i've edited in the other info. if there is more you should [edit it in](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/46523/edit) because it would make your question less opinion based which doesn't make a good question here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe Kishimoto wrote anything in regards to transition of the 4th to the 5th Raikage, but the selection of the [Raikage](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Raikage) is not touched on a whole lot and is unclear to us.

> How the Raikage is selected isn't clear; after the Third Raikage died, his son automatically became Fourth Raikage, a decision made many years earlier

It is possible [Killer B](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Killer_B) was nominated for the position, but we may never know. I can say that Killer B has no passion to being a Kage - his passion is music and his goal is to be greatest rapper. If he was nominated, Killer B may have turned it down, like Jiraiya, to pursue his passions

> Despite being responsible for the village's protection, B aspires to be the world's greatest rapper.

While there have been, and currently are, Kage who are jinchūriki, this does not automatically make them the next in line a Kage position. It is merely tradition for the next jinchūriki to be a relative of the current [Kage](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kage).

> Because jinchūriki were so important to their village, it was a tradition for a jinchūriki to be a relative of the current Kage, both to strengthen the jinchūriki's loyalties to the village and to display the Kage's might.

Given that Killer B is the (adoptive) brother of the 4th Raikage, he became the jinchūriki for his brother.

> According to Motoi, the reason behind him becoming a jinchūriki was for the sake of his brother, even if it meant being shunned by the villagers